# How to parse JSON in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio

I am trying to figure out how to parse data that comes from Zoho CRM API inside of Android Studio. I am relatively new, but I do know how to parse data from a JSON response like this:

```
    {
      "Data": [
         { "subdata": "data"
     }
  ]
}
```

Something kind of like that I can parse no problem in Android Studio, even with multiple subdata points, it's not that hard. But, I am at a complete loss when it comes to parsing data that looks like this:

```
      {"response":{"result":{"Contacts":{"row":[{"no":"1","FL":
    [{"content":"1822766000000272057","val":"CONTACTID"},
{"content":"Lisa","val":"First Name"}]},{"no":"2","FL":
[{"content":"1822766000000119148","val":"CONTACTID"},
{"content":"Eric","val":"First 
Name"}]}]}},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Contacts/searchRecords"}}
```

Does anyone know how to parse data like this inside of Android Studio?

Update: I have a photo of what the JSON looks like in Json Viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take it layer by layer. It can get a little verbose so I like to have a class called JSONUtils or something and use convenience methods like this to help parsing JSON without having to wrap everything in try-catch blocks:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a json object from the passed in json object.
 * @param json The json object from which the returned json object will be retrieved.
 * @param key The key whose value is the json object to be returned.
 * @return A json object.
 * */
public static JSONObject jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(JSONObject json, String key) {
    try { 
        return json.getJSONObject(key); 
    }
    catch (JSONException e) { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

You can make variations of this for any other data types, and by doing so you can just have your try-catch blocks in one area, and just check for null when invoking these kind of methods.

```
JSONObject responseJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(json, "response");
if (responseJSON != null) {
    JSONObject resultJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(responseJSON, "result");
    // So on and so forth...
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions on this. Where would I put my URL that has the JSON I want to parse in this instance? Also, in the code block: JSONObject responseJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(json, "response");   it says json cannot resolve symbol, how do I fix that? I created a separate JSONUtils Class.

Comment: "json" would be whatever you're trying to parse (i.e. The json object you posted in your question). You can really put your URL wherever it makes sense in your app, you would just use the convenience methods to parse the response of the URL that you are making the request to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using as a web service, but for example OkHttp uses callbacks with the response of the request as a parameter. You would then parse that value using variations of the method I posted above.

Comment: Awesome! I managed to get it down to the row. Now, it goes down to multiple objects, ill call them main objects, then multiple arrays for each object, ill call them main arrays, then multiple objects after that, ill call them sub-objects. So would I use a for loop for each main objects, then call the main arrays, then do another for loop for each of the sub-objects?

Comment: Yup! I can edit my answer to show you the gist of that if you need help, just let me know.

Comment: Cool. I'm going to work on that right now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Fantastic! I have everything working now and my data is being parsed properly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, and I noticed you were relatively new so welcome to SO! If an answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That lets everyone know your issue has been resolved for future reference.